# tox/pytest tests pass/fail depending on whether another module is installed in host environment

Tags: python, pip, pytest, tox

I have a number of `pytest` tests, deployed using `tox`, that install an old version of a module, then import it, then install a newer version of the same module. The tests check that upgrading a module that has already been loaded raises a warning (to tell the user to restart the session/interpreter).

My problem is that the success of the tests depends on whether the old version of the module is installed in the host environment (e.g. `pip install --user random_module && tox` or `pip uninstall random_module && tox`). I was very surprised to discover that the tests were sensitive to what I had installed in my user. What is going on, and how do I avoid that interaction so that the tests run the same, regardless of what is installed in my user's `site-packages`?

#### More information about the project

I am writing [a wrapper package for pip to allow installing packages from inside a REPL/console/script](https://github.com/reynoldsnlp/pip_inside). One complication that this raises is that someone could have already loaded a module, and then install an upgrade, but the old version will remain in memory. In these cases, I need to warn to user that they need to restart their session for the new installation to take effect.

Comment: I have cloned the master branch, ran `pip install "pytest<5" && tox -e py37`, then `pip install "pytest>=5" && tox -e py37`, but had identical test results. How can I reproduce the issue?

Comment: @hoefling On branch `#3-origin`, do `git pull`, then `tox` should pass all but one, but `python3 -m pip install --user progress==1.4 && tox` should fail on 3. The tests are dependent on the `progress` package, which is kind of a hack for now. Eventually, I'll put toy packages in my test folder to play with.

Comment: I see what you mean, I can indeed reproduce it - however, I don't think it has smth to do with the current env as `tox` runs the tests in own isolated env. I think it has something to do with the tests not cleaning up the installation of `progress` - try running e.g. `.tox/py36/bin/pytest tests/functional/test_install.py::test_progress_already_loaded_warning`, the test result will alternate between failure/pass, depending on what's left installed after the previous execution.

Comment: E.g. run `.tox/py36/bin/pytest tests/functional/test_install.py::test_progress_already_loaded_warning; .tox/py36/bin/pip show progress | grep Version` to see what I mean.

Comment: Of course! I was assuming that the virtual environment was reinitialized every time, but it actually persists. I see in [the docs](https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example/basic.html#forcing-re-creation-of-virtual-environments) that you can use the `--recreate` flag to make it run fresh. Thx for your help, @hoefling! If you want to make your comments into an answer, I'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with two tests switching between failing/passing is the installation of the `progress` package not being rolled back between test runs. One possible solution would be enforcing recreation of the virtual env by `tox` via running `tox --recreate`, as you have suggested in the comments. Another would be implementing a rollback in a fixture, e.g.

```
@pytest.fixture
def rollback_progress_package():
    yield  # wait for the test to finish
    subprocess.run(['pip', 'install', '--force-reinstall', 'progress==1.5'])

@pytest.mark.usefixtures('rollback_progress_package')
def test_progress_already_loaded_warning():
    ...
```

This has the nice effect that the rollback can be done in between the test run and not just once per run when the virtual env is recreated.